# What does 'vanishing' mean in the context of Linear Algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, terminology

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian

The line under 'Wronskian and linear independence' is what I'm talking about.

When you take the determinant of a matrix with linearly dependent vectors, doesn't it make the determinant $0$? Is going to $0$ what they are talking about?

Comment: "Mathematics. (of a number, quantity, or function) to become zero."

Comment: In particular, the Kodaira vanishing theorem says that a certain group is zero, not that either Kodaira or his theorem vanished.

Answer (score 9):

It's traditional mathematical English to say "$x$ vanishes" to mean $x = 0$.

Answer (score 4):

Your interpretation is correct. "The Wronskian vanishes" means the Wronskian is equal to $0$.